# Column value be max value of another column where another value is the same

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I need to update a column in the table... Let's call it `MaxUsers`, with the amount of different rows for the same User. So we have 4 columns:

```
Column 0: Unique ID
Column 1: User (Unique User ID, is the same for all subuser)
Column 2: SubUser Nr (this is 0 if it is the main user)
Column 3: MaxUsers (Maximum Subuser on this User)
```

I need column 3 (MaxUsers) to be the maximum number of Column 2 (SubUser Nr) where Row 1 is the same (User) is the same

I can do this in Linq on C# or even in python, but I am a bit of a newbie on SQL and doing over there would  use many more queries than I think is needed, and I am pretty sure my method is not the most efficient.

If I was to do this in C# I would do it like this assuming the SQL database is queryable in LINQ:

```
// Grab all main users to an array
var MainUsers = SQLDatabase.Where(x => x.SubUser == 0).toArray();
// Go through them one by one
for(int i = 0;i < MainUsers.length();i++)
{
    // Find all users in this user ID
    var Group = SQLDatabase.Where(x => x.User = MainUsers[i].User).toArray();
    // Go through each subuser
    for(int o = 0; o < Group.Length();o++){
        // If the subuser nr is bigger than the maxusers change it to that
        if(Group[o].SubUserNr > Group[0]MaxUsers){
            Group[0]MaxUsers = Group[o].SubUserNr;
        }
    }
    // Sets the subusers to max value too
    for(int o = 0; o < Group.Length();o++){
       Group[o].MaxUsers = Group[0]MaxUsers
    }
}
SQLDatabase.SaveChanges();
```

The final result would look like this

```
Row  :UID / User / SubUser Nr/ MaxUsers
Row 0:0 / 10 / 0 / 3
Row 1:1 / 10 / 1 / 3
Row 2:2 / 10 / 2 / 3
Row 3:3 / 10 / 3 / 3
Row 4:4 / 15 / 0 / 4
Row 5:5 / 15 / 1 / 4
Row 6:6 / 15 / 2 / 4
Row 7:7 / 15 / 3 / 4
Row 8:8 / 15 / 4 / 4
Row 9:9 / 17 / 0 / 1
Row 10:10 / 17 / 1 / 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should achieve what you want:

```
UPDATE Users u
JOIN (SELECT uid, MAX(SubUser) AS max
      FROM Users
      GROUP BY uid) AS t
ON u.uid = t.uid
SET u.MaxUsers = t.max
```

It should take the max "subuser" for each user id, and then update the main user table with those values

Answer (score 0):

Join two subqueries:

```
select t1.UID
, t1.User
, t1.[SubUser Nr]
, t2.MaxUsers
from (
    select t.UID
    , t.User
    , t.[SubUser Nr]
    from tbl t
) t1
  inner join (
    select t.UID
    , t.User
    , max(t.[SubUser Nr]) as MaxUsers
    from tbl t
    group by t.UID
    , t.User
) t2 on t2.UID = t1.UID
    and t2.User = t1.User
```

Or you may be able to use a correlated subquery.

```
select t1.UID
, t1.User
, t1.[SubUser Nr]
, (select max(t2.[SubUser Nr]
   from tbl t2
   where t2.User = t1.User) as MaxUsers

from tbl t1
```

(Sorry, my experience is in SQL Server.  The syntax may need to be adjusted for MySQL.)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question correctly, but I believe ultimately you want to have an extra column that tells you the latest user record to use?

```
            var MainUsers = SQLDatabase.Where(x => x.SubUser == 0);

        foreach (var user in MainUsers)
        {
            user.MaxUsers = MainUsers.Where(x => x.UID == user.UID).Max(x => x.SubUser);
        }
```

Or you do not necessarily need to have an extra column but select in SQL by this query:

```
select UID, User, Max(SubUser)
from t1
group by UID, User, SubUser
```

Comment: This was great, thank you very much, it is the simplest one, I just wonder if it is fast enough to do a few million rows.

Comment: If your ultimate goal is to have the max value in an actual column of your database, doing it on the database side will always be faster than programatically, assuming you have proper indexes on your table

Comment: No problem. Linq is fast enough, try not to make it to an array, as it cost more runtime computation.

Comment: Like Pepper mentioned, if you are running in SQL size and you have proper index, it should take you 1 second for the execution of the query.